# Playa inside channel entries

Tags: playa

I have a home channel in which I want to display various Playa fields bringing entries in from other channels. It's tricky though, home is a listing item as it will change everyday (Note the start and stop). The information Playa brings in is also from a listing.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="home" limit="1" start_on="{current_time format="%Y-%m-%d 00:00"}" stop_before="{current_time format="%Y-%m-%d 23:59"}"}

{exp:playa:children channel="articles" field_id="18" parse="inward"}
{title}
{/exp:playa:children}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The problem here is that the Playa field always shows the title from the home listing, not the article listing even though I specified the channel in the Playa field. From looking at the Playa docs, this should work fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the simple fieldtype tag pair for the playa child entries loop to see if that returns the data you're looking for?

```
{cf_your_playa_field_short_name}
  {title}
{/cf_your_playa_field_short_name}
```

Comment: That works! I wonder why this simple example isn't in the docs and why the exp:playa one is.

Comment: It is but it's way down at the bottom of the docs. I tend to lean on the exp:playa tag pair, but when it isn't behaving quite the way I expect, sometimes simply reverting to the fieldtype tag pair is the simplest solution. I'm not sure how it compares tag-wise, but on the surface it seems to mirror exactly what exp:playa:children is supposed to do.

Comment: You're right, well spotted. Thanks again for your simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I get it but I'll take a shot. parse=inward is not needed here, nor is the field_id I don't think. Also, I would use single quotes inside double quotes to avoid parsing problems. The following code should work provided that:

- a home entry is displayed by the outer channel entries tag
- you have entries belonging to the "articles" channel that are playa children of the "home" entry and that have a status of "open"

Could you give it a try?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="home" limit="1" start_on="{current_time format='%Y-%m-%d 00:00'}" stop_before="{current_time format='%Y-%m-%d 23:59'}"}

    <h1>home entry title: {title}</h1>
    {exp:playa:children channel="articles"}
        <h2>article entry title: {title}</h2>
    {/exp:playa:children}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found the solution which is posted below. I appreciate you leaving an answer!

Comment: Hey Paul, exp:playa:children should work as well IMHO. In fact I have very similar working code. Would be interested in finding out what the problem was in your case.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is I use the Stash module. I wonder if parse order is stopping it from working.

Comment: Well, difficult to know without the full context but, in the code samples you gave, if there is no stash code between your father entry loop and playa:children either should work I think. Thanks for getting back on that. Glad you got it working in the end.